# Creating random points along polylines using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, geometry, random

I'm trying to draw random points along the polylines. The polyline layer and the number of points to create are given as input. My problem is that the points are being created for every single line existing in the layer, so if as an input I'm setting 5 points the result is 5 points for every line, not 5 points in general. Below is my code:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import mp
import os
import random

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

aprx_path = 'CURRENT'
aprx = mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)

map = aprx.listMaps()[0]

# Getting all values from the tool
input_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
points_nb = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Description od input layer:
description = arcpy.Describe(input_layer)

try:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_layer, ['SHAPE@']) as search_cursor:
        # Creating output feature class:
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
                    os.path.dirname(output_layer),
                    os.path.basename(output_layer),
                    geometry_type="POINT",
                    spatial_reference=description.spatialReference)
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_layer, ['SHAPE@']) as insert_cursor:
            for row in search_cursor:
                line = row[0]
                if line:
                    spaces_length = float(random.randint(0,int(line.length)))
                    for i in range(0, int(points_nb)):
                        insert_cursor.insertRow( [ line.positionAlongLine(spaces_length) ] )
                        spaces_length += float(random.randint(0,int(line.length)))
            
            map.addDataFromPath(input_layer) 

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work properly?

Comment: Create 5 random points and snap them to edge of nearest line.

Comment: I think you should remove the try/except and include some print statements while testing and presenting code here.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel here, have you searched for "random points" on the [esri code sharing website](http://codesharing.arcgis.com/)?

Comment: Your code logic generates five point per feature. If you want five features total you need to change the code.

Comment: To elaborate on @Vince's comment, your `for` loop inside your `if line` statement should not be there. It should be moved outside of your `try` statement, perhaps. And you'll need to randomise the lines that are being chosen. Otherwise, it'll be the first five lines all the time. Perhaps try choosing 5 random lines and then create a point randomly on each one of them.